# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in the eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;

public class TestFindingElement {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://google.com");

    }

}
```

When I execute the above code in the eclipse. Throwing the following error.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hc/core5/http/ClassicHttpRequest
at testcases.TestFindingElement.main(TestFindingElement.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hc.core5.http.ClassicHttpRequest
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 1 more

I check the classpath and did refresh the project still getting the same error. however, When I ran the simple print statement no error will be display. please help me I am so frustrated with the error for two days.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a maven project, add this dependency to your POM.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.3</version>
  </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this program "WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();" this line will not work on only java,

1.Try via maven and java : if you are using  maven-java-selenium go with already used line of "WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();" and add dependency mentioned below,
[https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/5.3.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzjCp.png)

2. if its not maven add a jar of "WebDriverManager" in your java project
3. Else instead of this line "WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();", you can go with "System.setproperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","mention your chromedriver path which already have in your system");